# Access the Object Keys of all the files inside a specific subfolder of s3 bucket

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a s3 bucket inside which there are many subfolders.
I want to print just the keys of all the files from the specific subfolder '**abcxyz**' 
inside that bucket

Succeeded in achieving the files of just that subfolder with the following code:

```
import boto3, os, sys
from botocore.client import Config


# Removed my credentials here on StackOverflow
ACCESS_KEY_ID = ''
ACCESS_SECRET_KEY = ''
BUCKET_NAME = ''


s3 = boto3.resource(
    's3',
    aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=ACCESS_SECRET_KEY,
    config=Config(signature_version='s3v4')
)

my_bucket = s3.Bucket(BUCKET_NAME) 
for obj in my_bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=Folder_name + '/'):
    print(obj)
```

It's giving me output as:

```
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='', key='abcxyz/1.jpg')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='', key='abcxyz/2.jpg')
s3.ObjectSummary(bucket_name='', key='abcxyz/3.jpg')
.
.
.
```

and so on.. (Removed the bucket name here)

I want to print just the key name of all the files like:

```
abcxyz/1.jpg
abcxyz/2.jpg
abcxyz/3.jpg
.
.
.
```

Referred the links:

https://alexwlchan.net/2017/07/listing-s3-keys/

and

[Accessing a specific key in a s3 bucket using boto3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49470585/accessing-a-specific-key-in-a-s3-bucket-using-boto3)

But couldn't think out of the box. Could I get a help to print the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```py
print(obj.key)
```

You might want to string the sub-folder off the front.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a print(obj.key) it should get you there.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in the end, it will print

```
print (obj.get("Key").split("/")[1])
```